# Exporting list of list as labels of columns and rows in Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I am currently having a task where I need to export from Python into Excel two lists of lists as labels of columns and rows of an array. I tried various method with `xlsxwriter` package (particularly, the `write_row` and `write_column` functions) but so far I could only export each element of the "small" list (the one contained in the big list) into individual columns in Excel (which is not what I want. I want each small list into one separate cell in Excel). An example is following:

**Input from Python**

> list1 = [['a', 'a', 81, 81, 0, 0], ['b', 'b', 54, 54, 10, 10]]
> list2 = [['b', 'c', 50, 46, 0, 2, 0],['a', 'b', 21, 18, 10, 15]]
> name = [[0,1], [0,0]]

**Output in Excel**

[image]

Can someone please help me with this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openpyxl to create a worksheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

list1 = [['a', 'a', 81, 81, 0, 0], ['b', 'b', 54, 54, 10, 10]]
list2 = [['b', 'c', 50, 46, 0, 2, 0],['a', 'b', 21, 18, 10, 15]]
name = [[0,1], [0,0]]

for x in range(len(list1)):  # edges
   ws.cell(1,2+x).value  = str(list1[x])
   ws.cell(2+x,1).value  = str(list2[x])

for r in range(len(name)):  # center box
   for c in range(len(name[r])):
       ws.cell(2+r, 2+c).value = name[r][c]

wb.save('out.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I tried out your code, but then it kept giving me this error for wrong data type regarding the `ws.cell(1, 2+x).value = str(list1[x])` line: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'upper'`

Comment: can you please help address why your code above gave the error I described?

Comment: Yes I got that error using your exact code. And my Python's version is 3.5 btw.

Comment: I tried 3 times and it still gave me the same error. Did it run on your Python? If it did, did you use Python 3.5?

Comment: Python 3.7.6. I ran it from the command line using the Anaconda distro.

Comment: I finally figured out how to resolve it, by specifying `ws.cell(row = ..., column = ...).` The result was correct. Thank you so much for your help!